# Looping through Angular Material Expansion Panel

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have created the Angular Material Expansion Panel but i want to create the expansion panels dynamically using the *ngFor loop where the data is coming from the JSON format and i am trying to bind that data to the expansion panel. For that i have created the code something like this. See below:

```
<mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let autocodeRes of autocodeConfig">{{autocodeRes}}
              <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                  Type : anonymous_invalid
                </mat-panel-title>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>

              <mat-form-field>
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
              </mat-form-field>
                   <br/>
                   <label>Severity</label>
             <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="severityGroup">
            <mat-radio-button color="primary" class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let sev of severity" [value]="sev">
              {{sev}}
            </mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
          <br/>
          <mat-checkbox type="checkbox" color="primary" name="size" (change)="0" check>Active</mat-checkbox>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-accordion>
```

The Service which i have created is as below:

```
private autocodeURL = './assets/auto-code.json';
//Auto-code for testing from static json file
getAutoCodeConfig(){
    return this.http.get(this.autocodeURL);
}
```

The component in which i am consuming the service is below:

```
listAutoCode() {
    this.handler.activateLoader();
    this.projectService.getAutoCodeConfig().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
        return;
      }
      this.autocodeConfig = results['data'];
      //this.length = results['totalElements'];
    }, error => {
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      this.handler.error(error);
    });
  }
```

The JSON is coming like this below.

```
{
   "generators": [
      {
         "type": "anonymous_invalid",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical"
      },
      {
         "type": "auth_invalid",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical"
      },
      {
         "type": "DDOS",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical",
         "matches": [
            {
               "name": "itemsPerPage"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type": "XSS_Injection",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical"
      },
      {
         "type": "sql_injection",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical",
         "database":
            {
               "name": "MySQL",
               "version": 5.7
            }
      },
      {
         "type": "sql_injection_timebound",
         "assertions": [
            "@ResponseTime >= 5000"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical",
         "matches":
            {
               "pathPatterns": "/api/**",
               "methods": null,
               "sample": "account-create, account-update, ...",
               "queryParams": "name,accessKey,...",
               "bodyProperties": "name, key,..."
            },
         "database":
         {
            "name": "MySQL",
            "version": 5.7
         }
      },
      {
         "type": "log_forging",
         "postfix": "log_forging",
         "patterns": [
            "pattern1",
            "pattern2"
         ],
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical"
      },
      {
         "type": "rbac",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode == 403"
         ],
         "severity": "Critical",
         "matches": [
            {
               "pathPatterns": "/api/**",
               "methods": null,
               "denyRoles": "Anonymous"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type": "invalid_datatype",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Major"
      },
      {
         "type": "special_chars",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Minor"
      },
      {
         "type": "negative_number",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Minor"
      },
      {
         "type": "null_value",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Minor"
      },
      {
         "type": "empty_value",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode != 200"
         ],
         "severity": "Minor",
         "inactive": null
      },
      {
         "type": "create",
         "assertions": [
            "@StatusCode == 200"
         ],
         "severity": null,
         "inactive": true
      }
   ]
}
```

See below image for better clarity.

[image]
I want to consume this json data and bind this data to Expansion panel which should loop and append all the json data to it. I tried in with the above code but its not working for me. Can anyone suggest me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `this.handler.handle(results)` do? And why do you want to return void if it's true? Does your run `this.autocodeConfig = results['data'];` properly?

Comment: I have fixed this. Here at this line this.autocodeConfig = results['data']; i have to add results['generators'] but i added results['data']. Because in API its mentionaed as generators. So i have redesigned the model and it got worked.